# Are thread IDs unique per process or per computer?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, thread-safety

Say, if I have a thread ID, can I be assured that it will be unique (for as long the thread is running) per process or throughout the OS (among all logged in users)?

Comment: Once you know that a thread can run on different cores/processors during its lifetime and that the ID will stay constant during that time, you can deduce the answer yourself ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, thread ID's and Process ID's on Windows are allocated from the same pool, so they will be unique. Once the thread or process ends however, the ID may be re-used by another thread or process.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know that PIDs are unique. I wasn't sure about thread IDs.

Comment: Could you expand your answer to explain how often thread ids or process ids get recycled?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek As soon as the kernel object is closed, its ID can be re-used. So the following is entirely possible: `hThread1 = CreateThread(...&tid1); CloseHandle(hThread1); hThread2 = CreateThread(...&tid2); // tid1 == tid2, even hThread1 == hThread2` Although they now refer to a different kernel object.

Comment: A PID or TID on Windows will also remain valid as long as there's still an open handle referencing the process or thread. This is kind-of implied by "as soon as the kernel object is closed" because the open handle also keeps the kernel object alive, I just wanted to clarify. So PID or TID reuse can only happen after the process/thread has ended _and_ the last handle referencing it has been closed.

Answer (score 9):

A thread is represented by a kernel object e.g. on Windows platform. Hence it's id will be unique across all processes across all logon sessions. However thread ids can be recycled after the thread kernel object is closed.

[GetCurrentThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183(v=vs.85).aspx) also clearly says about the unique id while running.

Comment: Thanks. To guard against thread ID recycling (if thread & its handle could be closed while tracking this thread ID is done) one can couple it with thread creation FILETIME, that could be obtained with GetThreadTimes() API.

Comment: @user843732: Done in the right way, yes you can. I use that technique to check if a process's parent PID indicates it's parent process vs. a process that has recycled it's parent's PID.

Comment: @parrowdice: One follow-up question, guys. The `FILETIME` timing returned by GetThreadTimes() API doesn't have any timer-related "jitter", does it? The docs claim that the value of thread creation is expressed in "100-nanosecond time units" which is an awful precise! It won't cause the internal timer to start rounding it up for different calls to that API, will it?

Comment: A `FILETIME` stuct is always 100ns ticks. That doesn't mean that the underlying APIs will actually ever return things that differ by one 100ns tick. Also, if something happens in less than 100ns, the values might be the same. All this being said, why do you care about this recycling? Knowing that might help answer the question better. (The follow up question is worrisome at present. All sort of alarm bells are currently going of in my head, telling me that we're being "too clever". :-] )

Comment: Thanks for the link! MSDN has a lot of documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but apparently they choose to hide this important bit of information in the documentation for a single function. :)

Comment: On it's own, the fact that a process or thread is related to/represented as a kernel object does not necessarily mean that the IDs which are used in userland to refer to them are unique. In theory, there could be some mapping like with file descriptors on *NIX systems. Also AFAIK not every kernel object even has an ID, AFAIK things like mutexes are only referenced via their address (kernel) or some handle referencing them.

Comment: @paul groke: Raymond Chen mentions in one of his blog posts - the same code that allocates kernel handles also allocates thead and process handles. Of course, it's an implementation detail and doesn't guarantee it won't change in the future...

Comment: @parrowdice A thread or process handle is very different from a thread or process ID. ID : thread/process is 1:1, handle vs thread/process is N : 1 (many handles can refer to the same thread/process object).